# Konsole does not open in current directory (pwd)

Tags: command-line, bash, pcmanfm, konsole

Some file managers, such as `pcmanfm` or `pcmanfm-qt`, open terminals in the current directory by setting `$PWD` before opening the terminal.  Most terminals behave as expected.  This includes `xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, and `xfce4-terminal`.  However, `konsole` always opens in a pre-specified directory (usually `$HOME`).

**How can `konsole` be made to respect `$PWD` as other terminals do?**

---

At the time this question was initially written, a patch had been submitted, but not accepted.  However, the patch appears to have since been accepted, so that Konsole in Ubuntu 22.04 behaves as expected.

- [When no working directory is specified, use the $PWD of konsole itself instead of $HOME](https://mail.kde.org/pipermail/konsole-devel/2012-April/019295.html)

This was a long-standing issue that had been around since at least 2010.

- [Konsole does not set initial working directory from cwd](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187754)
- [pcmanfm: opens Terminal in wrong folder](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=586030)
- [#991 'Open in terminal ' got wrong when using 2 panels](https://sourceforge.net/p/pcmanfm/bugs/991/)
- [How do I change the "default working" directory of terminal applications in RHEL6?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/109483)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: Recent versions of Konsole now respect `$PWD`.  However, this solution may still be of use because it shows how to customize Konsole behavior.  For instance, shells can be opened in tabs instead of new windows.

---

For several years, there has been no setting to make `konsole` respect `$PWD`.  However, there is a command-line option `--workdir` that can be exploited by a script to make `konsole` function as desired.

1. Check the path to locate a user-accessible location that takes precedence over `/usr/bin` by examining the output of `echo $PATH`.  Typical options include `~/bin/` and `~/.local/bin/`.
2. Create a file named `~/bin/konsole` (or `~/.local/bin/konsole`) with the following contents:

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    # make konsole respect $PWD, as other terminals do
    # save as ~/bin/konsole or ~/.local/bin/konsole

    # catch unset or mis-set PWD
    [[ -z $PWD ]] && PWD="$HOME"
    [[ "$PWD" == '/' ]] && PWD="$HOME"

    term_cls='konsole'      # window class needed for xdotool to activate window
    term_bin=`type -a -p konsole | tail -n 1`    # location of original `konsole`
    term_cmd=( "$term_bin" )

    [[ $PWD ]] && term_cmd+=( --workdir "$PWD" )
    term_tab=( "${term_cmd[@]}" --new-tab )

    case $1 in
      -h|--help|-v|--version|--author|--license|--list-profiles|--list-profile-properties)
        "$term_bin" "$1"
        ;;
      -p)
        echo 'cannot change profile properties at this time'
        ;;
      *)
        find_app=( xdotool search --onlyvisible --class "$term_cls" windowactivate exec "${term_tab[@]}" )
        "${find_app[@]}" || xdotool exec "${term_cmd[@]}"
        ;;
    esac
   ```
3. Give the new script execute permissions.

   ```
    chmod +x ~/bin/konsole
   ```

Now, whenever this script is run, it will process `$PWD` and execute `/usr/bin/konsole --workdir "$PWD"`.  If put in the right folder, it will have priority over the real `konsole` and usage will be transparent.  Similar scripts can be created for other programs that do not behave as desired.